# Erlang http clients fails under high load

Tags: http, erlang, client

I have some web service, written in Erlang. Due to some requests this service calls another web service in Erlang. The second service is very slow and some requests execution time reaches a minute. Requests count at time to this service is strongly limited and i use timeouts for all requests to this service. I've used different http clients: `gun`, `httpc`, `hackney` and others. Few minutes after start system behaves as expected, limited count of requests are sent, but then no requests sent at all. All http clients gives same result. A similar problem described here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.general/73146 Please, give me an advice, what could cause the problem? I've checked ulimit and other environment options, everything is ok.

Comment: What kind of computation does the backend (2nd service) operates? Slow IO might smell a lot of things, from the speed of your network, to any kind of bottleneck. Have you tried to simplify your requests?

Comment: Second service is an interface for Oracle DB and performs some queries to it. Because i have limited amount of connections to DB - many requests are queued and waiting for free connection to it. When http requests hangs at first service (no new connections at second service), second service is free and all connections to DB are available. When i just restart first service - everything works again for some time and situation repeats. As i understand - the problem is in many waiting http connections at a first service.

Answer (score 0):

You say you get the same behavior with all http clients, so I think that your code is the common variable.

A good start to debugging this would be to mock out the HTTP calls. Instead of

```
    {ok, Result} = httpc:request("http://my.oracle/dostuff")
```

use

```
do_request(_Url) ->
    {ok, {200, <<"fake results">>}}.

....
% inside some other method
    {ok, Result} = do_request("http://my.oracle/dostuff")
```

If this works, try modifying your `do_request` to sleep for a long time (simulating the slow response from your server).